# isRegistered not returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code should print out string in `sname` but it's not doing it. Not throwing any errors at all?

```
var Student = function(name, fee) {  
    if(fee >= 1000) { 
       this.registered = new Boolean(true);
    } else {
       this.registered = 'not rgistered yet'; 
    }
}  

Student.prototype.isRegistered = function() {
    return this.registered; 
}

var John = new Student('John', 1000);

if(John.isRegistered() === true) {
    $('#sname').text('John is now a registered student');
}
```

Comment: In addition to what the answers say, comparing a value against a boolean is not good practice (unless you *have to* to check the data type). So instead of writing `if ($foo === true)`, you'd just write `if ($foo)`.

Comment: `new Boolean(true) === true` is `false`.

Comment: @FelixKling Why comparing value against boolean is not best practice?

Comment: @JS-coder: Because the `if` statement is already doing that. It tests whether the expression evaluates to `true` or `false`. You don't have to do this explicitly (unless, as I said, you want to verify the data type). This is the same for returning a boolean. Bad code: `if ($foo) { return true; } else { return false; }`. Better code: `return $foo;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fchVv/1/)**

Your problem is with following line:

```
this.registered = new Boolean(true);
```

Never use `new` with primitive types in JS. This can be done with many fewer keystrokes:

```
this.registered = true;
```

`new boolean(false)` returns an object that has a `valueOf` method that returns the wrapped value instead of actual expectued value which is `true` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

`new Boolean(true)` creates an object of type boolean. so `===` fails since it does a type check as well. In actuality `typeof new Boolean(true)` is `object` and not `boolean`. So you need to get the value using [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method, which returns the primitive boolean value of your object.

For your code you should do:

```
if(John.isRegistered().valueOf() === true) {
```

Else just change it to primitive boolean.

```
if(fee >= 1000) { 
   this.registered = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Boolean(true) === true; // false
```

The reason for this is complicated, but the fix is simple.

There isn't really a good reason to forcefully use simple objects like `Boolean`, `String`, `Array` etc. Most browsers optimize the simple form: `true`, `""`, `[]`.

If you're heaving into prototyping it might be useful, but then you can't use `===` anyway.